# Dialog for closure misleading when question has been closed and re-opened

Tags: bug, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I noticed, when clicking "close" on this question: [Breakthroughs in mathematics in 2023](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461083), that when a question has been closed and re-opened, and you voted to close it previously, the dialog box says "You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote." Of course, I understand that you should not be able to vote again to close a question if it was then voted to be re-opened, but this dialog is misleading: I certainly never "retracted" my previous vote.

Can we change this dialog to be more accurate? Just something like "You cannot vote to close again if you have already voted to close" would be fine.

Comment: This has been reported on Meta SE, and is tagged [status-review]; see here: [When a retraction is not a retraction. Please update close-menu message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376335)